# Customizing the Placement of Labels Using {ggrepel} in a Donut Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, donut-chart

I am trying to create a donut plot with text box labels that **do not** overlap with the plot itself using {ggplot} and {ggrepel} in R. This has proven more difficult than anticipated. My code for the current donut plot along with what it looks like is below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

# Creating a Sample Data Frame
data <- data.frame(Column = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4"),
                   Value = c(86.5, 12.9, 0.0, 0.6),
                   Color = c("#007bc9", "#a50021", "#5ad5ff", "#002f80"),
                   Category = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                   Title = c("Variable 1", "Variable 2", "Variable 3", "Variable 4"))

# Customizing the Hole Size
hsize <- 2

# Creating the Donut Plot
donut <- data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hsize, y = Value, fill = Category)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = data$Color) +
  xlim(c(0.1, hsize + 0.5)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  ggtitle("Title") +
  theme(
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = NA),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = NA),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(
      color = "#002f80",
      face = "bold",
      hjust = 0.5,
      size = 16
    ),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  scale_y_reverse()

# Now I am Adding the Text Box Labels
donut <- donut +
  geom_label_repel(
    aes(label = paste0(
      str_wrap(Title),
      "\n",
      str_wrap(if_else(Value == 0, "0%", paste0(Value, "%")))
    )),
    color = "#002f80",
    size = 4,
    fill = "white",
    box.padding = 0.5,
    force = 10,
    force_pull = -0.9,
    direction = "both",
    segment.size = 0.7
  )
```

[image]

As you can see, the labels bleed onto the plot itself. I would like it so that two labels appear away from the plot on the left and right, respectively (one in the top-left, top-right, bottom-left, and bottom-right). I would prefer that **no** label touches the plot and that there is ample white space between the label and the plot. I have tried tons of iterations with various commands in {ggrepel} but I just can't seem to how to get this part right.

Comment: `eavs.long.vpm2$Value` does not seem to be defined, nor is `vpm`.

Comment: @Peter My bad! I copied the wrong line of code for the label section. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I missed the request to place the labels in the four corners of the plotting area.
Here's an initial go at label placement in plot corners, without {ggrepel} so I'm afraid no connector between the label and pie segment.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)


# Creating a Sample Data Frame
data <- data.frame(Column = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4"),
                   Value = c(86.5, 12.9, 0.0, 0.6),
                   Color = c("#007bc9", "#a50021", "#5ad5ff", "#002f80"),
                   Category = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                   Title = c("Variable 1", "Variable 2", "Variable 3", "Variable 4"))

# Customizing the Hole Size
hsize <- 2

data <- 
  data |> 
  mutate(lab = paste0(Title, "\n", Value, "%"),
         y_lab = cumsum(sum(Value) / 4))


# Creating the Donut Plot
data |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = hsize, y = Value, fill = Category)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = data$Color) +
  xlim(c(0.1, 5)) +
  ggtitle("Title") +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  geom_label(aes(x = 4.5, y = y_lab,
             label = lab),
             position = position_stack(vjust = .5),
             colour = "white")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

First attempt.
Does this go part of the way to what you a looking for?
I've simplified the graph a little just to clear some of the non-relevant (to your question) arguments and constructed the labels in the data frame rather than in ggplot.
There seems to be a balancing act going on between the x limits `xlim` and `nudge_x` in the call to `geom_label_repel`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggrepel)

data <- 
  data |> 
  mutate(lab = paste0(Title, "\n", Value, "%"))

# Customizing the Hole Size
hsize <- 2

# Creating the Donut Plot
 data |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = hsize, y = Value, fill = Category)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = data$Color) +
  xlim(c(0.1, hsize + 1)) +
  ggtitle("Title") +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = lab, y = Value, x = hsize +0.5),
                   color = "#002f80",
                   size = 4,
                   fill = "white",
                   box.padding = 0.5,
                   nudge_x = 0.3
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This definitely improves the labels. In the actual plot, I have more information within the labels. Given this extra info, the labels get quite large, overlapping and creating a mess when they are close to each other. That is why, in particular, I was trying to customize them so that I have one label in each corner of each quadrant effectively so that I didn't have to worry about this overlap.

Comment: Getting the labels into the plot corners is doable, see revised answer. Adding connectors seems a little more troubling. Have to leave this now.